# A group of parameter types that Blazor explicitly checks

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

In the [Avoid overwriting parameters in ASP.NET Core Blazor article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0), we can read:

> If StateHasChanged is called in a parent component, the Blazor
> framework rerenders child components if their parameters might have
> changed:
>
> - For a group of parameter types that Blazor explicitly checks, Blazor rerenders a child component if it detects that any of the parameters
>   have changed.
> - For unchecked parameter types, Blazor rerenders the child component regardless of whether or not the parameters have changed. Child
>   content falls into this category of parameter types because child
>   content is of type RenderFragment, which is a delegate that refers to
>   other mutable objects.

What types of parameters are exactly included in the group that Blazor explicitly checks?

Comment: What's your use case here? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I'm not sure who marked this for deletion.  It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What types of parameters are exactly included in the group that Blazor explicitly checks?

Basically primitive and some known value types.  It doesn't detect objects such as records or readonly structs.

Here's the code the Renderer uses to determine if a value "may have changed", and therefore needs to call `SetParametersAsync` on a child component.

```cs
public static bool MayHaveChanged<T1, T2>(T1 oldValue, T2 newValue)
{
    var oldIsNotNull = oldValue != null;
    var newIsNotNull = newValue != null;

    // Only one is null so different
    if (oldIsNotNull != newIsNotNull)
        return true;

    var oldValueType = oldValue!.GetType();
    var newValueType = newValue!.GetType();

    // HERE
    if (oldValueType != newValueType)
        return true;

    if (!IsKnownImmutableType(oldValueType))
        return true;

    return !oldValue.Equals(newValue);
}

private static bool IsKnownImmutableType(Type type)
    => type.IsPrimitive
        || type == typeof(string)
        || type == typeof(DateTime)
        || type == typeof(Type)
        || type == typeof(decimal)
        || type == typeof(Guid);
```

Comment: Nice, I believe the implementation of `IsKnownImmutableType` answers my question.

Comment: There are ways to prevent rendering for other types by implementing a manual setter in the component.  See this MS article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually.  Check what you're setting and return a `TaskCompleted` if nothing has actually changed rather than calling base.